# What is the return of hg tags --template "{date|isodate}\n"

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using Mercurial "HG", I want to know what is the exactly output of

```
hg tags --template "{date|isodate}\n"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

prepare [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
hg init test1
cd test1
echo test this > file.txt
hg commit -A -m "my 1st commit"
hg tag mytag1
```

--

now try different templates for `tags`

normal `tags` output:

```
hg tags
tip        1:e02e6bf615f5
mytag1     0:0970400e2de4
```

--

now let's try with the tag name and the tag date in short format YYYY-MM-DD:

```
hg tags --template "{tag} {date|shortdate}\n"
tip 1970-01-01
mytag1 1970-01-01
```

--

and finally, the one you asked (with only the ISO date):

```
hg tags --template "{date|isodate}\n"
1970-01-01 00:00 +0000
1970-01-01 00:00 +0000
```

--

if your doubt is about the template filters:

```
hg help template
```

> isodate       Date. Returns the date in ISO 8601 format: "2009-08-18 13:00 +0200".